# Change variable returned as reference from object method PHP

Tags: php, oop, pointers, object, reference

I would like overwrite array element returned as reference. I can do it like this:

```
$tmp = $this->event_users_details;
$tmp = &$tmp->firstValue("surcharge");
$tmp += $debt_amount;
```

I would do it in one line like:

```
$this->event_users_details->firstValue("surcharge") += $debt_amount;
```

but I get `Can't use method return value in write context`

Where `$this->event_users_details` is a object injected in constructor.
My function look like:

```
public function & firstValue(string $property) {
    return $this->first()->{$property};
}

public function first() : EventUserDetails {
    return reset($this->users);
}
```

and `users` is a private array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it without temporary variable stores "surcharge" value.

[From documentation:](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php#example-150)

To return a reference from a function, use the reference operator & in both the function declaration and when assigning the returned value to a variable:

```php
<?php
function &returns_reference()
{
    return $someref;
}

$newref =& returns_reference();
?>
```

I checked it with this code:

```php
class Item
{
    public $foo = 0;
}

class Container
{
    private $arr = [];

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->arr = [new Item()];
    }

    public function &firstValue($propNme)
    {
        return $this->first()->{$propNme};
    }

    private function first()
    {
        return reset($this->arr);
    }
}

$container = new Container();
var_dump($value = &$container->firstValue('foo')); // 0
$value += 1;
var_dump($container->firstValue('foo')); // 1
```